# Applying the mean value theorem to sine function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Prove that  $ \pi x\cos(\frac{1}{2}\pi x^2) = c$ has a solution in $0 < x< 1$ for $c=1$?
> Is this true for all positive values of $c$?

I said define $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) =\sin(\frac{1}{2}\pi x^2)-cx$. Then $f$ is (in particular) continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ so by the MVT there exists $\xi \in (0,1)$ s.t. $f'(\xi) = \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0} = 1-c$. But also since $f$ is differentiable we can write $f'(\xi) = \pi \xi \cos(\frac{1}{2}\pi \xi^2)-c$.

So there does exist a solution when $c=1$ since then $f'(\xi) =0$.

Is it right to say that since $f'(\xi) = 1-c \ne 0$ for any $c \ne 1$, the equation has no solutions for all other positive values of $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not correct.  $f(x) =\pi x \cos (\frac {\pi x^{2}} 2)$ is a nonnegative continuous function on $[0,1]$ vanishing at $0$ and taking strictly positive values at other points. So it attains all values between $0$ and the maximum value. So $f(x)=c$ has  a solution in $(0,1)$ for all sufficiently small positive numbers $c$. But there is no solution when $c $ exceeds the maximum value. Actually it is easy to calculate the maximum value but I will leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you. Could I argue: we have $\pi x \cos (\frac{1}{2} \pi x^2) \le \pi x < \pi^2$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Hence by taking $c=\pi^2$ we see that it isn't true for all positive values of $c$? I'm trying to find a workaround because I'm not sure if the theorems available to me are enough to characterise for which values of $c$ it has a solution.

Comment: Yes, the argument for $\pi^{2}$ is correct. For finding all values of $c$for which there is  a solution I am only using Intermediate Value Property: a continuous function attains all values between its minimum and maximum values. So a solution exists off $0<c \leq M$ where $m$ is the maximum value. Do you how to find the maximum value by setting the derivative equal to $0$?  @DMX

Comment: Thanks. I see that the maximum value satisfies $\cot(\frac{1}{2} \pi x^2) = \pi x^2$, but I can't determine it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You properly showed that the maximum corresponds to
$$\pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x^2}{2}\right)-\pi ^2 x^2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi 
   x^2}{2}\right)=0$$
Let $\frac{\pi  x^2}{2}=y$ to reduce the problem to
$$\cos (y)-2 y \sin (y)=0$$ Use a series expansion around $y=0$ to get
$$\cos (y)-2 y \sin (y)=1-\frac{5 y^2}{2}+\frac{3 y^4}{8}-\frac{13 y^6}{720}+O\left(y^8\right)$$ which is a cubic in $y^2$.

It is has only one real root given by the hyperbolic method and then
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{13} \left(90-20 \sqrt{3} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{731 \sqrt{3}}{25}\right)\right)\right)}\approx 0.653266$$
while the exact solution, given by Newton method, is $0.653271$.

Just continue from here to have a quite good approximation.

**Edit**

Another possible solution could be to use the series expansion of
$$z=\cos (y)-2 y \sin (y) $$  and use series reversion to get
$$y^2=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n (z-1)^n$$ where the $a_n$ make the sequence
$$\left\{-\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{125},-\frac{68}{28125},\frac{293}{984375},-\frac{1672}
   {41015625},\frac{5449628}{913623046875},-\frac{126516512}{138566162109375}\right
   \}$$ which is not recognized by $OEIS$.

Making $z=0$ leads to
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{177404762809276}{415698486328125}} \approx  0.65327105$$  while the exact solution is  $0.65327119$

This makes, as an *approximation*,
$$c_{max}=1.608836120431054$$ while its exact value should be $1.608836120431092$.

None of these numbers are recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.